# Wordpress plugin - how to run a plugin randomly

Tags: wordpress, plugins, timing

I need to create a functionality on a wordpress plugin:

I need to insert a random numbers of time every day some information to a db table.

How would you do this in WordPress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [wp_schedule_event](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) its a cronjob.
A cron does run at a regular interval so you have to check the random part during the regular run of the cron

more WP cron:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Category:WP-Cron_Functions
http://wpengineer.com/1908/use-wordpress-cron/ <- tutorial

Comment: I'll give you a warning. cron jobs are a bitch. And that goes for every kind of cron not just wordpress cron.

Comment: What do you mean? Why are they so?

Comment: I don't have much experience with cronjobs. but you can imagine that because of the interval you will need to be patient to test everything even if you set the interval to 2 minutes.